# Loading Json data to WPF

Tags: c#, json, wpf, binding

I'm trying to load Json file into my  wpf project but it's not working..
Can you help me please? I watched many videos and still didn't find the right solution

After ruining program is throwin an exception "Error converting value "{" to type 'Test.MyLibrary', Path", line 3, position 1

This is my Json file "test.json".

```
{
                    "Name" : "Apple",  

                    "ExpiryDate" : "May",

                    "Price" : 3.99

                    }
```

This is my class MyLibrary

```
 class MyLibrary
{


        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ExpiryDate { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }

}
```

My C# code

```
public MainWindow()
    {

        string path = "test.json";
        String myStream= File.ReadAllText(path);
        InitializeComponent();


        try

        {

            MyLibrary myLibrary= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyLibrary>(myStream.ToString());

            DataContext = myLibrary;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {


            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
```

And now i want to show Name in WPF label

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyLibrary/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="firstLabel" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBox>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Price}"></Label>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

What i'm doing wrong ? Any ideas?

Comment: As a note `myStream.ToString()` is nonsense. Despite the name, `myStream` is already a string. Besides that, you certainly don't have the JSON file in the right place. `File.ReadAllText("test.json")` expects the file in the current directory of your application.

Comment: I have this file iny my project folder Debug. I can see this in program.

Comment: Then please write a more precise problem description. "it's not working" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: I already responded in bottom answer After ruining program is throwin an exception "Error converting value "{" to type 'Test.MyLibrary', Path", line 3, position 1

Comment: The problem description should be part of the question body, and not of a comment to some answer, so please edit your question. Besides that, your code works fine for me with your JSON file.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any error, exception? What is wrong? Also you didn't write which library you use for JSON serialization(I assume it is Newtonsoft.Json).

I tried your code but with one small change and works:

```
MyLibrary myLibrary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyLibrary>(@"{""Name"" : ""Apple"", ""ExpiryDate"" : ""May"", ""Price"" : 3.99}");
```

Comment: You're right. I' m using (Newtonsoft.Json). The point is when i declare my "json file" in string inside program then everything works fine. But my goal is make it by loading it from file. After ruining program is throwin an exception "Error converting value "{" to type 'Test.MyLibrary', Path", line 3, position 1